# /usr/local has correct permissions, but brew update still says it is not writable

Tags: permissions, homebrew

Here are the permissions to my `/usr/local` directory: `drwxr-xr-x`.

I did `sudo chown -R $user /usr/local`, then did `brew update` again. It didn't work. I tried quitting terminal and opening a new session and trying again and I got the same thing. When I try `brew doctor` or `brew update`, it tells me that this directory is not writable. What do I do? What else do I need to be checking?

Answer (score 1):

When I try to `brew update` Tip me `Error: / usr/local must be writable!`

1. `sudo chgrp -R admin /usr/local`
2. `sudo chmod -R g+w /usr/local`

The above method solves my problem

Answer (score 0):

You need to run `sudo chown -R $(whoami):admin /usr/local`. Also note that in the command you ran `$user` should be capitalized: `$USER`.